# How do i solve this and debug this because i already match it

Tags: c++, if-statement

> .cpp(27): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
>
> cpp(37): error C2181: illegal else without matching if

Hello, how to solve this problem
I want to build a program about discount and total cost of order

below is the code.. it say the problem but i cant correct it
thank you

```cpp
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;
#define retailPrice 20

int main() {
  float quantity, discount;
  float totalCost;

  cout << "Welcome to GLAMOUR bookstore,Enjoy our cool promotion.\n";
  cout << "Please enter the quantity of packages you have purchased:";
  cin >> quantity;
  {
    if (quantity < 0)
      cout << "Sorry,quantity cannot be negative\n";

    else if (0 <= quantity && quantity < 10)
      discount = '0';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice;
  }

  {
    if (10 <= quantity && quantity <= 19) discount = '20';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice * 0.8f;

    else if (20 <= quantity && quantity <= 49) discount = '30';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice * 0.7f;
  }

  {
    if (50 <= quantity && quantity <= 99) discount = '40';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice * 0.6f;

    else if (quantity >= 100) discount = '50';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice * 0.5f;
  }

  cout << "Total cost of purchase = RM" << totalCost << ".\n";
  cout << "discount =" << discount << "%\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The braces don't go outside the `if` blocks: `if (something) { ...} else {....}` [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](//stackoverflow.com/q/388242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors are causing by misplacement of parenthesis.
Check this code,I removed the errors from it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define retailPrice 20

int main()
{
float quantity,discount;
float totalCost;

cout << "Welcome to GLAMOUR bookstore,Enjoy our cool promotion.\n";
cout << "Please enter the quantity of packages you have purchased:";
cin >> quantity;

if (quantity<0){
    cout << "Sorry,quantity cannot be negative\n";
}
else if (0<=quantity && quantity<10){
    discount = '0';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice;
}

if   (10<=quantity && quantity<=19){
    discount = '20';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice*0.8f;
}
else if  (20<=quantity && quantity<=49){
    discount = '30';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice*0.7f;
}

if (50<=quantity && quantity<=99){
    discount = '40';
    totalCost = quantity * retailPrice*0.6f;
}
else if (quantity>=100){
    discount = '50';
totalCost = quantity * retailPrice*0.5f;
}
    cout << "Total cost of purchase = RM" << totalCost << ".\n";
    cout << "discount =" << discount << "%\n";
    return 0;
   }
```